# Find and match only first 5 character in 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Maybe u can help me with the formula.

Column 1 (named A) containt 2590 rows with 5 numbers like

```
12345
41266
71263
12653
71263
```

Column2 (named H) contains only 300 rows with numbers like:

```
71637126371623
67126317236173
61616161162542
71621762165265
```

I need to  match column1 and column2 and find rows in column2 which contains 5 digits numbers from column1

Comment: In the title you mention a match in the first five characters. So does the value in column H have to start with the values in column A, or does it have to contain the value?

Answer (score 0):

With Excel365 you can use `XLookUP()` like-

```
=XLOOKUP("*" & A1 & "*",B:B&"",ROW(B:B),"",2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to look whether the cells next to each other 1 is a substring of the other, you can get the result with `if`,`isnumber`,`search`, all in one:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2)),1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula to check this assuming your data starts from Row 2.

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(2,1/SEARCH($A$2:$A$6,H2,1),1))`

Depending on your Excel Version, you may or may not have to use Array entry to implement i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

**Edit:**
Based on @JvDV comment you can test position by using below construct.

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(2,1/(SEARCH($A$2:$A$6,H2,1)=1),1))`